# bootstrap modal footer css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put a spinner to the left of the boostrap3's modal dialog box's footer, but it hovers on top of one of the buttons, What am I doing wrong here?

```
 <div class="modal-footer">   
     <!-- Spinner --> 
     <span style="text-align: left" id="wait-spinner"></span>

     <!-- Cancel and Save changes button --> 
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SaveEditChanges()">Save changes</button>
 </div>
```

and here is the `wait-spinner` css:

```
 #wait-spinner {

      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      text-indent: -9999em;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: should i see future for css

Comment: Yes without your CSS for #wait-spinner we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: try this, good thing: http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks so much for introducing me to Ladda UI above, nice effects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code its clear  #wait-spinner is following position absolute in the div which have button

use `<span style="text-align: left" id="wait-spinner"></span>`

just inside the box or pop up where you want it with

```
#wait-spinner {

      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      top;50%;
      left:50%:
      text-indent: -9999em;
  }
```